# height of div not resizing after browserwindow resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's a short version of my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    resize();
});

$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    resize();
});

function doSomething() {
    wrapperobj = $(".wrapper");
    contentspanobj = $("#c");

    ............

    if (wrapperobj.length) {
        wrapperobj.height(....);
        wrapperobj.css({ overflow: 'auto' });
    }
    if (contentspanobj.length) {
        if (!wrapperobj.hasScrollBar()) {
            contentspanobj.height(wrapperobj.height() - 76);
        }
    }
    ............
}
```

if the wrapper shows the scrollbar the div should be resized, if not it just should fit to it's content.

following scenario:

1. no scrollbar shown, div resized with code
2. user reduce the window browser till scrollbar is shown
3. resize() is called
4. no resizing by code because there's no scrollbar

anyone has an idea how to get the div height fit to text? 
i can't use `.css("height", "100%")` because then it's using the height of the wrapper. the div height should be fit to the text which is added codebehind (asp.net)

thanks in advance

Comment: `.css("height", "auto")` will release the div to be held open by its contents.

Comment: haha thanks, works. should have known that :D

Comment: You need to present any CSS associated with the mark-up.